# Problema ao deserealizar objeto Json com VRaptor4

Tags: java, json, data, vraptor

Boa tarde Pessoal.

Estou tendo problemas ao deserealizar objeto json com VRaptor4.

Fazendo alguns teste, percebe uma situação:

Estou usando curl so para teste o serviço, porem quando faço esta requisição ex:
**curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "               {"id":1,"descricao":"Teste json"}"http://localhost:8080/meuProjeto/rest/salvarEvento**

o erro ocorre mas se eu tirar os espaços dos caracteres o objeto json, por exemplo: na descrição eu junto o valor **Teste json** para **Testejson** o deserializer funciona sem problema algum.

Podem me ajudar se isso esta ocorrendo por alguma falhar minha ou se pode ser algum problema no VRaptor4?

Meu método:

```
@Post
@Consumes("application/json")
public void salvarEvento(Anotacao anotacao) {
    System.out.println(anotacao.getDescricao());
    result.nothing();
}
```

Class:

```
public class Anotacao {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String descricao;
  @ManyToOne
  private Evento evento;
  @ManyToOne
  private Usuario usuario;
}
```

Error:

> br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.ResultException: Unable to deserialize data
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.serialization.gson.GsonDeserialization.deserialize(GsonDeserialization.java:151)
>     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.serialization.gson.GsonDeserialization$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deserialize(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.DeserializingObserver.deserializes(DeserializingObserver.java:91)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54226/discussion-on-question-by-giovani-felipe-problema-ao-deserealizar-objeto-json-co)